# Move Android application to SD instead of interal memory

Tags: android

In my manifest file, how can i tell the application to be installed in the sd memory instead of the internal memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` to the `<manifest>` element of your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.   Quoting the documentation for `preferExternal`:

> There is no guarantee that the system will honor this request. The application might be installed on internal storage if the external media is unavailable or full, or if the application uses the forward-locking mechanism (not supported on external storage). Once installed, the user can move the application to either internal or external storage through the system settings.